# Using an Arduino Weight Sensor, it fails to satisfy a while loop and I can't firgure out why

Tags: serial, sensors

```
/*

 This example code uses bogde's excellent library: https://github.com/bogde/HX711
 bogde's library is released under a GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE

 The HX711 does one thing well: read load cells. The breakout board is compatible with any wheat-stone bridge
 based load cell which should allow a user to measure everything from a few grams to tens of tons.
 Arduino pin 2 -> HX711 CLK
 3 -> DAT
 5V -> VCC
 GND -> GND

 The HX711 board can be powered from 2.7V to 5V so the Arduino 5V power should be fine.

*/

#include "HX711.h"
#include <Servo.h>

float calibration_factor = -4050.0;

#define DOUT  3
#define CLK  2
Servo myServo;

HX711 scale(DOUT, CLK);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Food Test");
    scale.tare(); //Assuming there is no weight on the scale at start up, reset the scale to 0
    Serial.println("Readings:");
    myServo.attach(9);
    long zero_factor = scale.read_average(); //Get a baseline reading
    Serial.print("Zero factor: "); //This can be used to remove the need to tare the scale. Useful in permanent scale projects.
    Serial.println(zero_factor);
}

void loop() {
    scale.set_scale(calibration_factor); //Adjust to this calibration factor

    if ((scale.get_units(), 1) <= 5) {
        Serial.print("whoa that is light, more food needed");
        myServo.write(90); // Open food hatch
        delay(2000);
        myServo.write(0);

        do {
            // Do nothing
            Serial.println("It is working somewhat");
            Serial.println(scale.get_units(), 1);
            delay(1000);
            // When weight exceeds 5 it should break out of this loop and go below
        } while ((scale.get_units(), 1) < 10);

        Serial.print("Closing the Hatch");
        myServo.write(0); // close food hatch
    } else {
        Serial.print("Something Went Wrong");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
It is working somewhat  
10.6
It is working somewhat
10.9
It is working somewhat
10.5
It is working somewhat
6.9
It is working somewhat
-0.8
```

I will try to explain the problem as best as I can. I am using a scale library and the `scale.get_units()`,x returns a value as a float. The whole point is that a servo will open and stay open until a specified weight of 10lbs is reached. As seen in the do, while loop that's what I specify. It jumps into the if loop and then into the do while loop, and it continually prints out values of readings which is what I want. BUT, even when I reach over 10lbs it will not break out of the Do/while loop, essentially it never satisfies the while condition and I have no clue why. It prints out values over 10 but keeps reading values. I know the format isn't the best but any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you have an extra bracket in there that you don't want.

At the moment your structure is:

```
if {
    do {
    }
} while...
```

As it stands your sketch won't compile. The unbalanced brackets prevent it.  Remove the excess one so that the `while` is associated with the `do` not the `if` and report back.

---

## Part II

The main cause of your problem is the strange bit of code you have in your `if`s and `while`s.

```
if ((scale.get_units(), 1) <= 5) {

....

} while ((scale.get_units(), 1) < 10);
```

In both of those you have the bit `(scale.get_units(), 1)` which is completely meaningless.  The comma operator in C calls (or evaluates) both sides, and then returns the right hand side.  So that calls `scale.get_units()` and then returns 1.  1 has always been, and will always be, less than 10, so the `while` never ends.

I don't know what you were hoping to achieve by having the `, 1` in there, but you should delete it from every place you have it.

Comment: Thank you for that fix, but it still wont break out of the do loop if the weight is greater than 10. Example: It is working somewhat
-0.6
It is working somewhat
13.8
It is working somewhat
-1.0
It is working somewhat
-5.4

Comment: Can you fix your sketch and replace your completely broken one with one that compiles? Also make sure you sort out your indentations - that would have immediately shown you the bad brackets.

Comment: Better. Now check my edit (Part II)

Comment: Well it hasn't fixed everything but it definitely helped me a ton, thank you so much for your help and support, I've been at it for hours but now I can actually breathe. Thank you!!!